# Problem in R with the gmn code "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Tags: r

Trying to do run this code:
`A <- gnm(wigooutwi ~ -1 + Dref(as.factor(domx$Womaneduc),as.factor(domx$Husbandeduc)),family = binomial, data = domx)`

But the error I got is

`Error in baseMatrix[, factorAssign == i] <- termTools[[i]] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

How can I fix this?

/

This is my whole code:

`install.packages("xlsx")`

`library(readxl)`

`domx <- read_excel("C:/Users/../Desktop/domx.xlsx")`

`View(domx)`

`install.packages("gnm")`

`require(gnm)`
`set.seed(1)`
`classMobility <- gnm(wigooutwi ~ -1 +            Dref(as.function((domx$Womaneduc),as.function(domx$Husbandeduc)),family = binomial, data = domx)`

`domx$neglectch +domx$argueswhu + domx$refuhsex + domx$burnsfood`

/

And the data is 0,1 and 2's.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @dmca yes, I'm following this link: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gnm/versions/1.1-0/topics/Dref under examples. If I only just copy paste it, I get the error that Husbanded, Woman is not a factor. And therefore I `add as.factor` before the variable.

Comment: Can you provide the code to load the required packages and to create the `domx` data frame?

Comment: @dmca i don't get it =/ this is my whole code: `install.packages("xlsx")
library(readxl)
domx <- read_excel("C:/Users/Julia/Desktop/domx.xlsx")
View(domx)

install.packages("gnm")

require(gnm)
set.seed(1)
classMobility <- gnm(wigooutwi ~ -1 + Dref(as.function((domx$Womaneduc),as.function(domx$Husbandeduc)),family = binomial, data = domx)

domx$neglectch +domx$argueswhu + domx$refuhsex + domx$burnsfood
`

Comment: Please encapsulate data and code in your example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some tips on how to do just that. Note that formatting (and thus readability) can be improved as well.

Comment: Your data comes from an excel file (`domx.xlsx`) that we can't access. If you can create a data frame using code that we can run on our machines we can recreate what you are doing.

Comment: @dmca do you mean 
`Husbandeduc <- c("1,1,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1")`
 `Womaneduc <- c("1,1,0,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2")`
 `wigooutwi <- c("0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1")`
 
` df<- data.frame(Husbandeduc,Womaneduc,wigooutwi)`
 `df`

Comment: @dmca This is the first 12 obsevations. So this is a smaller data frame.  Is this what you ment?

Comment: You need to update the code in your question so that anyone can run it. The way to test this is to start a new R session and run your whole code block from scratch. If you are reproducing the same error then it is more likely that we will be able to do so. [This guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) explains the details.